# React Native and right way to handle TextInput data?

Tags: android, user-interface, reactjs, native, textinput

I am making an app with react-native-maps and now I'm adding an UI.

I have faced this problem that I cannot change the text on an `TextInput` if the `Value` is the same as the value which will be updated on `onChangeText`. It gets emptied while I type.

I solved this by adding `this.forceUpdate()` right after changing the value, but this makes the app lag a bit and markers on the map are blinking when I type text.

The value is sometimes changed by code but sometimes its edited by user and read by code. What is the right way to handle this? `forceUpdate` doesn't feel right...

```
<TextInput
    keyboardType={'numeric'}
    style = {styles.textInput}
    value = {this.state.tmpCustomer.phoneNumber}                    
    onChangeText ={(text) => {this.state.tmpCustomer.phoneNumber=text; this.forceUpdate()}}
/>
```

Comment: Maybe `setState` would work? How do I `setState` a value inside an object (tmpCustomer) ?
I tried this but got an error (Unexpected token):
`onChangeText ={(text) => this.setState({tmpCustomer: { phoneNumber: text }); }`

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the lag by switching `onChangeText` to `onEndEditing` and removed `value` and used `setNativeProps` to change the text.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html

Comment: I was experiencing a very laggy keyboard + `onKeyPress`. By removing the `value` from it, it improved a lot on Android! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
<TextInput
    keyboardType={'numeric'}
    style = {styles.textInput}
    value = {this.state.tmpCustomer.phoneNumber}                    
    onChangeText ={(text) => { 
        const {tmpCustomer} = this.state;
        tmpCustomer.phoneNumber = text;
        this.setState({tmpCustomer : tmpCustomer});
    }}
/>
```

`setState()` will update compnent, so there is no need to `forceUpdate` (which usage, to be honest, you should avoid)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing performance issues with React Native's TextInput too. I solved this by using `defaultValue` as opposed to `value`, and allowing the component to re-render **only** when a focus/blur event occurs using `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

See below for an example.

```
export default class TextField extends React.Component {
    state = {
        value: '',
        touched: false
    };

    handleChange = (text) => {
        this.setState({
            value: text
        });
    };

    handleFocus = () => {
        this.setState({
            touched: true
        });
    };

    handleBlur = () => {
        this.setState({
            touched: false
        });
    };

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        const currentTouched = this.state.touched;
        const nextTouched = nextState.touched;

        // Re-render when the user has focused or unfocused the text field
        return (currentTouched !== nextTouched);
    }

    render() {
        const {value} = this.state;

        return (
            <TextInput
                // Use defaultValue to set the text field's default value upon render
                defaultValue={value}
                onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                onChangeText={this.handleChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
```